# SwiftUI Navigation Bar hide is not working

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

How Can I hide NavigationBar.

it works in this way respectively:
1- OnboardingView
2- MainView
3- LoginView
4- StepView

I don't want the NavigationBar on the StepView screen. I couldn't hide the NavigationBar with the code below.

I shared the screenshot below with you.

```
struct StepView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
        .navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

**OnboardingView**

```
struct OnboardingView: View {
    
    @State var currentPageIndex = 0
    @State var next: Bool = false
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var subviews = [
        UIHostingController(rootView: SubView(imageString: "OnboardingImageOne")),
        UIHostingController(rootView: SubView(imageString: "OnboardingImageOne")),
        UIHostingController(rootView: SubView(imageString: "OnboardingImageOne"))
    ]
    var titles = ["Take some time out", "Conquer personal hindrances", "Create a peaceful mind"]
    var captions =  ["Take your time out and bring awareness into your everyday life", "Meditating helps you dealing with anxiety and other psychic problems", "Regular medidation sessions creates a peaceful inner mind"]
    
    let coloredNavAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    init() {
        coloredNavAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        coloredNavAppearance.backgroundColor = .clear
        coloredNavAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        coloredNavAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredNavAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredNavAppearance

    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                    ...
                VStack {
                    
                    PageControl(numberOfPages: subviews.count, currentPageIndex: $currentPageIndex)
                    NavigationLink(destination: MainView(), isActive: $next) {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.next = true
                            self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                        }) {
                            Text("Devam Et")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding(.vertical,25)
                                .padding(.horizontal,UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3)
                        }
                        .background(Color("ColorWelcome"))
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                    }
                }
            }
            
            .background(Color("ColorOnboarding").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    HStack {

                                        Text("Walker")
                                        Image("logo")
                                        Text("App")

                                    }
                                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, alignment: .center)
            )
             ...
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

**MainView**

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var loginView: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        
        
        ZStack{
            Image("Welcomebg")
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, alignment: .top)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image("WelcomeImage")
                Text("Description")
                Spacer()
                
                NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(), isActive: $loginView) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.loginView = true
                    }) {
                        Text("GİRİŞ YAP")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.vertical,25)
                            .padding(.horizontal,UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3)
                            .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay-Bold", size: 14))
                    }
                    .background(Color("ColorOnboarding"))
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .padding(.top,20)
                }
             ...
        }
}
```

**LoginView**

```
    struct LoginView: View {
        
    ZStack {
               ...          
            NavigationLink(
                destination: StepView(),
                isActive: $isOpenStepView,
                label: {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        if emailAddress.count > 6 {
                            self.isLoginSuccess = true
                            self.showingAlert = true
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                                self.isOpenStepView = true
                            }
                        } else {
                            
                            self.isLoginSuccess = false
                            self.showingAlert = true
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("GİRİŞ YAP")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.vertical,25)
                            .padding(.horizontal,UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3)
                            .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay-Bold", size: 14))
                    }
                    .background(Color("ColorOnboarding"))
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .padding(.top,20)
                })
                ...
            }
  }
```

**StepView:**

```
struct StepView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
        .navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

[image: Screen shoot]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62657005/12299030?

Comment: This works, but I didn't want to use environmentobject.

Comment: How did you pass it does not really matter (almost) - the root of solution is that you need to hide it via dynamic property in first screen containing NavigationView.

Comment: @Asperi thank you sir. I solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigation Bar hide is not working in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027529/navigation-bar-hide-is-not-working-in-swiftui)